# Ruby on Rails - undefined method `category' for #<Post:0x000055a44cf6bd00> Did you mean? category_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, cloud, undefined

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlnf5.png) 
I am learning Ruby on Rails in college right now and I am struggling with it. I have a project to be finished in the next days but I cannot find out what is wrong with my code, I have tried to fix for it, I googled it already but no luck.

Due to the coronavirus the educational institutions are closed and I am unable to ask my lecturer for assistance on this.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out on this?

My application is very simple, it is a place where people can post whatever they want, however, they need to choose a category and other people can comment on it.

The error I am getting displayed on the browser is the below:

undefined method 'category' for #

Did you mean? category_id

Trace of template inclusion: #

app/views/layouts/_breadcrumb_nav.html.erb:21
app/views/layout/application.html.erb:16

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"3"}

My code where the error is been displayed is the below:

Below is the /app/views/layouts/_breadcrumb_nav.html.erb

```
<!-- Check if there is a post present, a category is present and handle these two scenarios differently, also includes a default link back to the home page -->
<div class="inner">

  <!-- Check if the user is signed in, otherwise just show the normal link -->
  <% if account_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_account_session_path, method: :delete, class: "pull-right m-l-10" %>
    <% else %>

  <%= link_to "Account", root_path, class: "pull-right m-l-10" %>
    <% end %>

  <%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path, class: "pull-right" %>

  <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> >>

  <!-- Do not show category if category if it is new entry and has no category set yet
       check out application_helper.rb
  -->

  <% if @post.present? && !@post.new_record?
       category = @post.category
       parent = category.parent if category.present?
  %>


    <% if parent.present? %>
      <%= link_to parent.name, category_path(parent) %> >>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %> >>
    <%= @post.title %>
  <% elsif @category.present?
       parent = @category.parent
  %>
    <% if parent.present? %>
      <%= link_to parent.name, category_path(parent) %> >>
    <%end %>

      <%= @category.name %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Below is the /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Marketplace</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>


  <div class="header" >
    <%= render "layouts/breadcrumb_nav" %>
  </div>


  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>


    <!-- divs for the menu -->
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main-left">
        <p><strong><%= link_to "Marketplace", root_path %></strong></p>

        <!-- Hides the Create a New Post menu once the user leaves the home page -->
        <p><%= link_to "Create a New Post", new_post_path %></p>

        <!-- User login - devise gem-->
        <p><%= link_to "User Login", new_account_session_path unless account_signed_in? %></p>

        <!-- load in categories if the user on a category page, only loads if the categories controller is being used -->
        <%= render "categories/category_sidebar"  if controller.controller_name == "categories" %>



        <% if is_home? %>
        <div class="nav-pages">
          <p><%= link_to "faqs, help", faqs_path %></p>
          <p><%= link_to "learn more about marketplace", about_path %></p>
          <p><%= link_to "avoid scams, fraud, safety tips", fraud_path %></p>
          <p><%= link_to "terms of use", terms_path %></p>
        </div>
        <% end %>

      </div>
      <div class="main-right">

    <%= yield %>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the /app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # Setting up the relationship in the DB
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts
end
```

I have a little bit of knowledge of Java and Ruby on Rails is killing me and I hope you can help me out.

Many thanks
Richard

Comment: What does your `Post` model look like? If I had to make a guess, it's missing `belongs_to :category`

Comment: Can you describe what this code is even supposed to do? Are you trying to build a breadcrumb navigation or something?

Comment: Hi guys,

Thank you very much for getting back to me and sorry if my question was not clear enough. I am trying to create a sort of marketplace where people can post whatever they wish and others can comment on it, it is divided between categories and subcategories, and since trying to implement the breadcrumb feature everytime I go to create a new post or click on a post to read it I get the error I've posted about.

Comment: I was trying to implement more the breadcrumb_nav.htm.erb

However I get the: undefined method 'category' for #<Post:XXXXXX>
Did you mean? category_id

Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/layout/application.html.erb locals=[]

app/views/layouts/_breadcrumb_nav.html.erb:21
app/views/layout/application.html.erb:16

Comment: Guys I've edited my post, I hope it is clear now the issues I am having. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your trying to to build something like a breadcrumb navigation that looks something like this:

```
Authors >> French >> Albert Camus
```

Start by setting up the associations:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  # lets you call post.parent_category without dealing with nil errors
  has_one :parent_category, 
    through: :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :parent_category, 
    class_name: 'Category',
    optional: true
end
```

Then DRY the code [into a partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) instead of making soup out of your ERB.

```
# app/views/posts/_breadcrumbs.html.erb
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <% [post.parent_category, post.category].compact.each do |c| %>
    <%= link_to c.name, c %> &raquo;
  <% end %>
  <%= post.name %>
</div>
```

`&raquo;` looks like ». If you actually want to use `>>` you need to escape it `&gt;&gt;` or use `<%= content_tag(:span, '>>') %>` as `>` has special significance in HTML.

Then render the partial in the view where you want it:

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'breadcrumbs', post: @post %>
```

Comment: I didn't think having one(or many) through a belongs to relationship worked

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery it does actually work fine. Don't knock it until you have tried it.

Comment: No it was a genuine question. I vaguely remember trying it a while and getting an error. I'm glad it works and will try it again in some of my personal projects :D

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. I actually had to verify that it worked myself before writing the question. Its not really that commonly used but its a good alternative to `delegate :foo, to: :bar` as it lets you include/eager load it.

Comment: Hi guys,

Thank you very much for getting back to me and sorry if my question was not clear enough. I am trying to create a sort of marketplace where people can post whatever they wish and others can comment on it, it is divided between categories and subcategories, and since trying to implement the breadcrumb feature everytime I go to create a new post or click on a post to read it I get the error I've posted about.

Comment: I was trying to implement more the breadcrumb_nav.htm.erb

However I get the undefined method 'category' for #<Post:XXXXXX>
Did you mean? category_id

Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/layout/application.html.erb locals=[]

app/views/layouts/_breadcrumb_nav.html.erb:21
app/views/layout/application.html.erb:16

Comment: Guys I've edited my post, I hope it is clear now the issues I am having. Thank you very much for your help :)